# Increase the dot from \dot and ring from \mathring in size

Tags: symbols

**Context** : I'm using `\dot{}` and `\mathring{}` commands, but they are way too small to be noticed if you are not reading with full attention. Sometimes, it is hard to distinguish between them both.

Illustration for the `\dot{}` command : [image]

Illustration for the `\mathring{}` command : [image]

**My problem** : I would like to make both the dot and the ring bigger so that they are easier to read. I have a book in which the ring looks better than what I have, so I'm guessing it is possible even if I can't find a clue about how to do it.
Detexify is not suited for this kind of research nor did I find answers on [the MathJax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Somehow I tried the `\Huge{}` command, but it changed nothing.

I take any suggestion, especially if they are quite simple ! Thanks for your time !

Comment: Which math font does your document employ?

Comment: @Mico I'm using the default math font.

Comment: Your question mentions MathJax.  Should your question be tagged as such, if indeed you are using MathJax?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm not using MathJax. I just brought up the basic tutorial since it present many basic commands such as the one I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the `accents` package: this package center the symbols below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}


\begin{document}
\[\accentset{\circ}{G}\]

\[\accentset{\bigcirc}{G}\]


\[\accentset{\bullet}{G}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is working, thanks ! I still hope to find a solution where I can have a bit more room for maneuver, but I'll be satisfied with this for now.

Comment: @MatthieuJentile I am happy to have helped you. Have a good LaTeX and enjoy your work. My regards